# R API using Plumber under Azure API Management CORS error

Tags: r, azure, azure-api-management, plumber

I'm trying to create some APIs in `R` with `Plumber`. I have managed to publish the API on a server and I can access them via browser: Swagger is exposed without any authentication. The code is

```
# api.R

#* Echo back the input
#* @param msg The message to echo
#* @get /echo
function(msg="") {
  list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}

#* Plot a histogram
#* @serializer png
#* @get /plot
function() {
  rand <- rnorm(100)
  hist(rand)
}

#* Return the sum of two numbers
#* @param a The first number to add
#* @param b The second number to add
#* @post /sum
function(a, b) {
  as.numeric(a) + as.numeric(b)
}

#* @filter cors
cors <- function(res) {
    res$setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    plumber::forward()
}
```

and there are working.

[image]

I want to protect them and I think to use Azure API Management service. I have created the service and added the APIs using the Swagger document. Also, I added `CORS` (as I saw in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62040830/azure-api-management-origin-header-was-missing-or-empty-and-the-request-was-cl)) in the **Inbound processing**.

[image]

In **Settings** I didn't change anything although I should use `OpenID connect`.

[image]

There is a simple api `/echo` that requires *msg* as parameter. If I run the test for this api, I receive 400 Bad Request.

[image]

In the Trace I have this error for 3 times:

> cors (0.020 ms)
> "Origin header was missing or empty and the request was classified as not cross-domain. CORS policy was not applied."

I can't find what the error is about. Also, I `Enable CORS` in the `Developer Portal` although I think it is totally unrelated.

What did I do wrong? What is the correct configuration?

Comment: That *“Origin header was missing or empty and the request was classified as not cross-domain. CORS policy was not applied"* is itself not an error. It’s just informative. It’s juste telling you that he server got a request without an Origin header, and therefore it didn’t apply the configured CORS policy. But if you somehow have the server configured to send back a 400 error if the CORS policy isn’t applied, then I guess that would be the cause. And the solution would be to respond with a 200 even if the CORS policy isn’t applied, and not a 400.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was tricky to find. I assumed that when I paste or type the Swagger documentation URL (like `http://51.123.13.2:8000/openapi.json`) Azure sets also the `Web Service URL` based on the Swagger URL. But it doesn't. The default value is `https://apimanagement.hosting.portal.azure.net`.

So, I changed in the `Settings` the value of `Web Service URL` with `http://51.123.13.2:8000` and it is working.